How to remove unnecessary projects of referenced libraries/projects
I remember enabling/changing some settings in Unity IDE in the past to view the codes and projects of the projects that the program uses.
But now, with too many projects loaded, it's just messy and I want to remove them.
What am I supposed to do?

I searched through project settings and preferences to find the setting I modified, but couldn't figure out what it was

This setting is in Edit->Preferences...->External Tools. Only set the Embedded Packages and Local Packages (those are the default settings). Then press Regenerate project files.
If any unwanted *.csproj or *.sln still stay in the root directory of your project folder you are safe to remove them. Unity will regenerate required project files if they're missing.


in the build setting exist an option by the name ( stripping ) . start from there. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html
